# Is there a way to extract the type parameters of a list inside a list in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to get the parameters of a type such as List that is nested inside another List.

For example, how would you extract the type of a nested List from a field such as this:

```
List<List<String>> strings
```

I found a way to do this one level deep:

```
for (Field field : aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    //checking if field type can have parameters, for example List<String>
    if(List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) || Map.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        //extracting type parameters, to do this you need to cast a type to ParameterizedType and then to Class to get a simple name easily
        List<Class<?>> typeParameters = Stream.of(((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments())
                .map(type -> (Class<?>) type)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //for a field like List<String> strings; this will print out: strings: List<String>
        System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " +
                        field.getType().getSimpleName() + "<" +
                        typeParameters.stream().map(Class::getSimpleName).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +
                        "> ");

    }
}
```

However, I haven't had any success with scaling it up for nested types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that getActualTypeArguments returns an array of Type and not an array of Class.
So you need to do the same thing recursively: if getActualTypeArguments[0] instanceof ParameterizedType, you can again call getActualTypeArguments on it and obtain the generic type of the inner list.

Note also that you code may throw exceptions because getActualTypeArguments don't necessarily return instances of Class, for example if your list was `List<? extends Object>`.